# How to setup gitolite and gerrit on separate ubuntu servers?

Tags: ubuntu, gerrit, gitolite

I would like to setup gitolite on one ubuntu server. This gitolite is used to host git repositories. I would like to setup gerrit on different ubuntu server and it uses git repositories hosted on gitolite server. Is it possible? If yes, please provide setup steps.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible if the Gitolite server shares the repositories via e.g. NFS to the Gerrit server. Gerrit needs to "own" the repositories by accessing them through a mounted file system.

But why would you want to do this? Running two repository managers seems like asking for trouble. If you don't want to use Gerrit's code review features everywhere or all of the time that's fine; Gerrit can be configured to allow direct pushes that bypass the code review step.

Comment: We already have Gitolite deployed in production and we do not want to change it. We want Gerrit to be used for code review and on successful review, Gerrit can push changes to Gitolite.

Comment: As you mentioned, NFS is one way. Thanks.

Comment: @Rakesh: Does Gitolite have a feature that Gerrit doesn't have? Otherwise maintaining dual infrastructure seems pointless.