# Install Gerrit and git on different machines

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a scenario. I have two instances, instance 1 for Gerrit and instance 2 for Git. I want to understand how will git intercept the requests coming directly to instance 2?
It can be safely assumed that I have to install gerrit only remotely, and not on the git instance.

While initializing gerrit, the interactive cli screen asks for the git repository location which is supposed to be a local(?) directory, like /home/me/git-repo (inside git-repo I have my project.git files). What if instead of a local repository, I specify a remote repository URI, say ssh://git@git.machine.com/root/project.git, first of all, will it work? If yes, how it is really intercepting all the push,pull... requests coming to ssh://git@git.machine.com/root/?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760661/how-to-setup-gitolite-and-gerrit-on-separate-ubuntu-servers/26774084.

Comment: Thanks for the link Magnus. However, the thing is, I want gerrit to 'take care' of only one repository (of the many repositories) in the remote folder. One way is to provide full permissions, on all other repositories (if we do this, everyone needs to setup git-review on their machines locally, which we don't want). We want only a specific group of people (working on a specific repository) to use gerrit. Why bother everyone when all of them will not be using the services of gerrit.

Comment: No, your users won't have to set up git-review. Gerrit's review features are optional and you can use it as general-purpose Git hosting software like e.g. Gitolite. Nobody will be bothered by switching to Gerrit (apart from the migration itself).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. First understand that gerrit is going to act as a staging workplace for your remote git. Which means that when a user submits the patch-set it first needs to go to Gerrrit's git workspace. Typically $GERRIT_HOME/git/. Now one need to enable replication in order to sync this repo to the remote git server where they want to submit the code eventually. Some useful link on replication setup and git projects setup can be found here:

https://review.typo3.org/plugins/replication/Documentation/config.html

[Importing already existing git repo with multiple branches and tags into gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514459/importing-already-existing-git-repo-with-multiple-branches-and-tags-into-gerrit)

Sample replication.config which may help you:

```
[remote "github-remote-name"]
    url = git@<remote-git-server>/${name}.git
```

Keep in mind that this ${name} is a magic keyword which is required to be matched with the repo that you want to sync. In order to sync selective repos of many that you may have, follow the guidelines in the link above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I noticed that you mentioned ${name} keyword helps me to keep gerrit in sync with any "specific" repository. I have a small follow up to that, is there a way to achieve the same result locally? I mean, I want to enforce gerrit-review only on a specific repository (say product.git) and not on utilities.git, both of which may be present in the same folder. One way is to grant full permissions to all the users on utilities.git, bu this like circumventing the rules to achieve a result. Is there a direct way for this? Thanks in advance.